# Set cultureinfo into listview xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to convert a currency value to the culture of a specific country. In the code behind it works perfectly, but I don't know how to do it in a listview.

Code behind

```
TotalLabel.Text = MyDouble.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CL"));
```

How can I do it in a listview?

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <ViewCell >
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0"   Text="{Binding Price,StringFormat='{0:C}'}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0"   Text="{Binding Total,StringFormat='{0:C}'}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource entryReadOnlyStyle}"/>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Could you help me?. Thank you

Comment: not sure if there is an easy way to do it in XAML, but you could use a ValueConverter, or bake it into your ViewModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a converter. Here's an example of how to write and consume it in your XAML page.

First create a class called `CurrencyCultureConverter` or something like that

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace YourApp.Converters 
{
    public class CurrencyCultureConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.ToString("C0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-CL"));
        }
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML

```
...
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:YourApp.Converters;assembly=YourApp"
...

<ResourceDictionary>
    <converter:CurrencyCultureConverter x:Key="CurrencyCultureConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>


<Label ... Text="{Binding Price,Converter={StaticResource CurrencyCultureConverter}}" BackgroundColor="Transparent" ... />
```